# Is it advisable to use a 'plugin' for this purpose or a seperate website?

Tags: html, plugins, web

Our college  has a website with our marks in it.
We don't have access to the server of the site.

I can only access the source code of our marks' site page.

**I wish to calculate the total of all the marks by parsing the numbers from the source code(HTML)and adding it.**

1)Is it advisable to build a plugin for that ??

Or do we need to build a site??

2)Is it possible to parse HTML that way to find out the marks??

**Some additional details** : 
We access the site for our marks , but we dont get the total of all the subjects.So,we open calculator and then manually enter the marks.

I want to build something that would display the total of all the marks.
So,I want users to know their total when they are on the college's site itself.

**Which solution would be best??A plugin or site or any other?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is really a too general question. But I will do some assumptions...

1) If you mean a browser plug-in, probably not. Most people would just write a script (using e.g. Python) to parse the HTML and generate the average. A plug-in is overkill except if you want it to be easier to use for a lot of people.

2) Parsing HTML is always possible. I'm assuming your brains could do it, so a computer can too. There are several HTML-parsers out there. For python [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) may suffice. There are probably enough out there for your language of choice.

Comment: Thanks @timo,why is a plugin overkill, is it difficult to build or any other? i have no idea of it. Can u let me know please?

Comment: You would usually need to use the specific API for the browser you're using. Each browser would require another API. But I'm not an expert so there may be cross-browser frameworks I'm not aware of.
Also, a browser plug-in is just the same functionality a stand-alone script is offering but wrapped within the plug-in.